# File upload using BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) and AJAX

Tags: ajax, file-upload, microsoft-bits, bits-service

does anyone know if it is possible to do a file upload using the BITS protocoll? The protocol is HTML1.1, so in theory it should be possible.

Any ideas are appriciated.

Thanks,
. Ivar

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible ... that's what BITS is for. The BITS client machine can initiate one of 3 job types: 1) download, 2) upload, and 3) upload-with-reply.

Usually, people use this by setting up an IIS virtual directory with the BITS Server Extensions, which means IIS will play the server role in the BITS protocol. But the protocol is documented, which means you can write your own BITS server (and your own BITS client as well if you want).

[Here's a link to the protocol documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362828(VS.85).aspx), and [here's a link to the general BITS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968799(v=VS.85).aspx).